# Doctrine MappingException on ManyToOne Relation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, mapping

Doctrine is failing to persist the user object.

```php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $Name;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $Picture;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=50) **/
    public $Phone;

    /** @Column(type="date") **/
    public $Birthdate;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="project", mappedBy="Owner")
     */
    public $Projects;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="user")
     * @JoinColumn(name="credentials_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $Credentials;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="skill", mappedBy="User_id")
    */
    public $Experiences;    

    /** @Column(type="string", length=2500) **/
    public $Motivation;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=2500) **/
    public $SoftSkills;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $Profession;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $EducationDegree;


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }    
}
```

after this call on the Entity Manager, it throws a MappingException.

```php
$this->entityManager->persist($this->user);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: The
>   target-entity Businessrelations\Database\project cannot be found in
>   'Businessrelations\Database\User#Projects

But at this point there are no Projects registered yet. Do i have to mark it as optional somehow? I also wondered what the '#' between User and Projects means. Does someone know?

**EDIT**

I changed the targetEntity attributes to a full qualified class name as suggested in related topics.

I found the corresponding source code on github:
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/e1bb9e005d2676c42ec19521db9569a28da179d3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php